# devise callback authenticate_user! не редиректит

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Добрый день.
Не получается с помощью devise реализовать следующий сценарий:
Пользователь входит в систему
Пользователь открывает форму для создания объекта
Пользователь выходит из системы
Пользователь пытается создать объект через форму
Пользователя редеректит на страницу входа с уведомлением

Проблема в том, что когда я из браузера пытаюсь послать запрос, то приложение падает, на ошибке:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '/', path_names: { sign_in: 'login' }

  resources :questions, only: [:index, :new, :show, :create, :destroy] do
    resources :answers, only: [:create, :destroy], shallow: true
  end

  root 'questions#index'
end
```

controller

```
    class AnswersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]

      def create
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
        @answer.user = current_user
        @answer.save
        redirect_to @question
      end
```

Форма

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = form_for [@question, @answer] do |f|
    .errors
    .form-group
    = f.label :body, t('.you_answer')
    = f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group
    = f.submit t('.asked'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

layout

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title ProSampleApp
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    .container-fluid
      #main.col-md-10
        - flash.each do |message_type, message|
          %div{'class' => "alert alert-#{message_type}"}
            - Array(message).each do |msg|
              %li= msg
        = yield
```

app controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :show404

  protected

  def show404
    render file: 'public/404.html', status: :not_found, layout: false
  end
end
```

Comment: Покажите ваш layout, вызов csrf_meta_tags в нем присутствует?

Comment: Devise ни при чём, похоже. В запроса нет CSRF-токена. Покажите, как запрос выглядит в логах. В частности, `params`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderShvaykin/05a7fa8ce8d589854f573f94c7492ae2

Comment: если вызывать `authenticate_user!` не через `before_action`, а через `prepend_before_action`, то работает.

Comment: ...ха-а, похоже, я неправ. И объяснение есть [в ридми Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers). Возможно. Или я опять ошибаюсь. Надо понять, в каком порядке вызываются эти `before_action`'ы. И не помешает знать версию Rails.

Comment: rails -v Rails 5.0.0

Comment: Добавил ApplicationController, `before_action` только один.